# Fresco not Working with FFmpegAndroid Library

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

Im using

```
implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

in my project when I implement Fresco Image not getting displayed.
And when I remove `FFmpegAndroid` from Gradle then `Fresco` start working

Comment: What error do you see? Have you implemented a `ControllerListener`? Can you please try logging if `onFailure` gets called when loading image? https://frescolib.org/docs/listening-to-events.html